# NameError: name 'userpword' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x

This is my coourse work, i am meant to create a program that generates a strong password checks the strength of a user inputed one and has a quit option. i originally did this on tkinter but came across a problem so i decide it to do it text based first and if i had a couple horse left over at the end then convert it into tkinter.

I do not understand why but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/course work.py", line 148, in <module>
    menureturn()
  File "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/course work.py", line 65, in menureturn
    checktheuserspassword()
  File "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/course work.py", line 26, in checktheuserspassword
    if re.search("[0-9]", x):
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

I have tried a nuber of stuff but not anything that i expect to solve it as to be honest i dont understand what the problem is. I searched online for help but i only found awnsers that were too diffrent from my case to work.(I've been stuck with this problem almost 2 hours now)

This is my whole code:

```
import random
import re
#import tkinter.messagebox as tm
def menureturn():
    print("Select one of the following numbers: ")
    print("1) Check Password")     
    print("2) Generate Password")
    x=input(print("3) Quit"))
    if x=="1":
        def checktheuserspassword():
            def userpasswordlength():
                userpword=input("Please enter a password you wish to be checked: ")
                if len(userpword)<=8 :
                    print ("Your password is too short, please enter a longer one (8-12 characters")
                    userpasswordlength()
                if len(userpword)>=12 :
                    print ("Your password is too long, please enter a shorter one (8-12 characters")
                    userpasswordlength()
                x=len(userpword)
            userpasswordlength()
            point=0
            contain=1
            symbol=set("[QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890!$%^&*()-_=+]")
            point+=int(x)
            if re.search("[0-9]", userpword):
                point += 5
                contain+= 1
            if re.search("[a-z]", userpword):
                point+=5
                contain+= 1
            if re.search("[A-Z]", userpword):
                point+=5
                contain+= 1
            if any((c in symbol)for c in userpword):
                point+=5
                contain+= 1
            if contain==5:
                point+=10
            for line in userpword.splitlines():
                line=line.strip()
                if re.search(r'^[a-z]+$',line):
                    continue
                if re.search(r'^[A-Z]+$',line):
                    continue 
                if re.search(r'^[a-zA-Z]+$',line):   
                    point -=5
            if userpword.isdigit():
                point -= 5
            if userpword.islower():
                point -= 5
            if userpword.isupper():
                point -= 5
            if re.match("^[!$%^&*()-_=+]*$", userpword):
                point -= 5

            if (point > 20):
                print("Your passwords strength is strong.")
            if (point > 10) and point<20:
                print("Your passwords strength is decent.")
            if (point < 20):
                print("Your passwords strength is weak.")
            else:
                checktheuserspassword()
        checktheuserspassword()
            #checker for users password
        print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        backfromgentomenu=input("Type \"Back\" to go back to the menu \nor \"Quit\" to quit: ").lower()
        if backfromgentomenu=="back":
            menureturn()
        if backfromgentomenu=="quit":
            quit  






    if x=="2":
        print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print("Password Generator")

        #passwordstrength=input("Please type the strength you wish your randomly generated password to be (Strong,Medium or Weak)").lower()
        def checkthegeneratedpassword():
            passwordgenerated1="".join(random.choice("QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890!$%^&*()-_=+") for i in range(random.randint(8,12)))
            point=0
            contain=1
            symbol=set("[!$%^&*()-_=+]")
            point+=len(passwordgenerated1)
            if re.search("[0-9]", passwordgenerated1):
                point += 5
                contain+= 1
            if re.search("[a-z]", passwordgenerated1):
                point+=5
                contain+= 1
            if re.search("[A-Z]", passwordgenerated1):
                point+=5
                contain+= 1
            if any((c in symbol)for c in passwordgenerated1):
                point+=5
                contain+= 1
            if contain==5:
                point+=10
            for line in passwordgenerated1.splitlines():
                line=line.strip()
                if re.search(r'^[a-z]+$',line):
                    continue
                if re.search(r'^[A-Z]+$',line):
                    continue 
                if re.search(r'^[a-zA-Z]+$',line):   
                    point -=5
            if passwordgenerated1.isdigit():
                point -= 5
            if passwordgenerated1.islower():
                point -= 5
            if passwordgenerated1.isupper():
                point -= 5
            if re.match("^[!$%^&*()-_=+]*$", passwordgenerated1):
                point -= 5

            if (point > 20):
                print(passwordgenerated1)
            else:
                checkthegeneratedpassword()
        checkthegeneratedpassword()
            #checker for gen
        print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        backfromgentomenu=input("Type \"Back\" to go back to the menu \nor \"Quit\" to quit: ").lower()
        if backfromgentomenu=="back":
            menureturn()
        if backfromgentomenu=="quit":
            quit







    if x=="3":
        print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        areyousuresimple=input("Are you sure you wish to quit?").lower()
        if areyousuresimple=="yes":
            quit
        elif areyousuresimple=="no" or areyousuresimple=="back":
            print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
            menureturn()
menureturn()
```

Thank you for your help.

(If you know where i can find a solution to this that would also be helpfull)

Comment: Tip: Don't define functions inside of if conditions

Comment: `userpword` is only defined inside the `userpasswordlength()` function, and you're trying to access it outside the function.

Comment: ^^^^^^ what i was going to say - you beat me to it, also, research PEP and see if you can improve your code formatting; because, my, my, what a mess of a code!

Comment: what shouldi do instead , i struggle finding other paths instead of what i originally thought of

Comment: your code looks like it needs a python tutor, not a Q&A site - go research some python formatting.

Comment: You can put all the `def` functions at the very left edge of the code. Also learn how to use `return` and function parameters if you are going to use functions at all

Comment: ohh thx i got it woring now

Answer (score 0):

`x` is not defined witin scope of the function.

Define your function elsewhere. For example, break your code into smaller functions

Check the length

```
def userpasswordlength(userpword):

    if len(userpword)<=8 :
        print ("Your password is too short, please enter a longer one (8-12 characters")
        return False
    elif len(userpword)>=12 :
        print ("Your password is too long, please enter a shorter one (8-12 characters")
        return False

    return True
```

Check the characters

```
def checktheuserspassword(userpword):

    # TODO: re.search  and things

    return True
```

And run your "menu" to call out to the other functions

```
def menureturn():
    print("Select one of the following numbers: ")
    print("1) Check Password")     
    print("2) Generate Password")
    print("3) Quit")
    x=input()
    if x == "1":
        userpword=input("Please enter a password you wish to be checked: ")
        points = 0
        valid_length = False
        while not valid_length:
            valid_length = userpasswordlength(userpword)
            points += 1

        valid_characters = False
        while not valid_characters:
            valid_characters = checktheuserspassword(userpword)
            points += 1
```